# socket connection getting closed abruptly with code 141

Tags: c, sockets

What im trying to do is connect to a remote server , read contents from a file on the local machine  and send it over to the server. Then capture the server response and save it. I put the GET command in a text file and am trying get the results of the same. Here is some part of the code.  Im doing this using sockets and C.

```
if ( inet_pton(AF_INET,ip, &(nc_args->destaddr.sin_addr.s_addr)) <= 0 )
    printf("\n\t\t inet_pton error");


if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &nc_args->destaddr, sizeof(&nc_args->destaddr)) < 0)
{
    printf("\n\t\t Connection error");
    exit(1);
}
puts("\n\t\t Connection successful to ...");

// file parameter is taken from command line and passéd to this function

fp = fopen(file,"rb");
if ( fp == NULL)
{
    printf("\n\t\t File not found");
    exit(3);
}

else
{
    printf("\n\t\t Found file %s\n", file);

    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    file_size = ftell(fp);
    rewind(fp);

    //allocate memory to the buffer dynamically

    buffer = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*file_size);
    if (buffer == NULL) {fputs ("Memory error",stderr); exit (2);}
    for (i=0 ; i<sizeof(buffer); i++)
    {
        printf("\n\t\t %s", buffer);
    }
    printf("\n\t\t File contains %ld bytes!\n", file_size);
    printf("\n\t\t Sending the file now");
}


while (1)
{
    bytes_read = fread(buffer,1, file_size, fp);
     printf("\n\t\t The bytes read is %zd", bytes_read);
    if (bytes_read == 0) // We're done reading from the file
      {
          printf("\n\t\t The bytes read is %zd", bytes_read);
          break;
      }
    if (bytes_read < 0)
    {
        printf("\n\t\t ERROR reading from file");
    }

    void *p = buffer;

    while (bytes_read > 0)
    {
        ssize_t bytes_written = send(sockfd, buffer, bytes_read,0);
        if (bytes_written <= 0)
        {
           printf("\n\t\t ERROR writing to socket\n");
        }
        bytes_read -= bytes_written;
        p += bytes_written;
        printf("\n\t\t Bytes %zd written", bytes_written);
    }
}

printf("\n\n\t\t Sending complete.");
```

What is happening here is that i get the message "connection successful", then it displays "sending the file now" and then the program quits unexpectedly. if i do echo $? i get 141 as the exit code. I am trying to connect from my server to a different server at work and get the results. These two can communicate correctly, and i can run the GET command from command line without issues. Its just not working from the code. Can someone let me know what the issue could be ?

Answer (score 11):

On Linux, and probably other Unixes, the return code encodes a signal that the process received. Here it is `141 - 128` so `13` which corresponds to `SIGPIPE`.

If you don't want that signal to be raised because you capture the error return of [`send`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/send), anyhow, on Linux you can use `MSG_NOSIGNAL` in the `flags` argument to `send` to inhibit that signal. On other platforms you might have to program more complicated signal handlers to deal with that situation.

Comment: why do you subtract the return code from 128?  The reutnr value "141" is the number of bytes sent.  Otherwise, if there were an error, it would reutnr -1, and you'd have to check errno for the error information.  http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sendmsg.2.html

Comment: @Magn3s1um the shell adds 128 so you can distinguish between exit codes (usually low numbers) and fatal signals (also low numbers). Otherwise death by `SIGHUP` would look the same as `exit(1)`

Comment: I see, he's checking it in the shell.  Missed htat part

Comment: hit same thing, quickly fixed it due to this SO anwer, so +1.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I would never have figured out why my program was silently terminating without this!

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof(&nc_args->destaddr)` is the wrong thing to pass to `connect`. It wants the size of the address, not the size of a pointer to the address.

And this loop:

```
for (i=0 ; i<sizeof(buffer); i++)
{
    printf("\n\t\t %s", buffer);
}
```

is baffling. `buffer` is a pointer, as we can see from when it was assigned a vlue returned by `malloc`. So its size is going to be 4 or 8 bytes on 32-bit and 64-bit architectures respectively; not related to the size of the malloc'ed object it points to. The loop runs 4 or 8 times, and prints... the same thing each time. Why?

Comment: okay that was just for testing, i was trying out some stuff, irrelevant to the goal. I also changed the connect function arguments, buts still getting the same error