# Program exits on SSL_connect

Tags: c++, ssl

I'm having a problem where my program that I'm working on will shut down immediately after a call to SSL_connect(). I can't get any error code from it what so ever, since calling SSL_get_error() afterwards will just be ignored since it exits the program. If I just do a normal http request with connect() it works fine. Anyone have any ideas on this?

I'm running this on the Raspberry Pi 3 with Raspbian.
I'm very new to SSL, so any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Here's a code snippet of what I'm trying to do

```
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <resolv.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
        int sockfd;
        struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
        int rv;

        memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
        hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
        hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

        if ((rv = getaddrinfo("www.example.com", "https", &hints, &servinfo)) != 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo : %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
            exit(1);
        }

        SSL_load_error_strings();
        SSL_library_init();
        ssl_ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_client_method());

        SSL * connection = SSL_new(int sockfd;
        struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
        int rv;

        memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
        hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
        hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

        if ((rv = getaddrinfo("www.example.com", "https", &hints, &servinfo)) != 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo : %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
            exit(1);
        }

        SSL_load_error_strings();
        SSL_library_init();
        ssl_ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_client_method());

        SSL * connection = SSL_new(ssl_ctx);

        for (p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next)
        {
            if ((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype,
                p->ai_protocol)) == -1) 
                {
                    perror("socket");
                    continue;
                }
            int fd = SSL_set_fd(connection, sockfd);

                break;
        }

        if (p == NULL) 
        {
            // looped off the end of the list with no connection
            fprintf(stderr, "failed to connect\n");
            exit(2);
        }
        int connRet = 0;
        while(connRet != 1 )
        {
            connRet = SSL_connect(connection);
            cout << "Error : " << SSL_get_error(connection, connRet) << endl;

        }



        freeaddrinfo(servinfo);
return 0;
}
```

EDIT 2 : Finally managed to run it through the debugger, now I'm getting :

(program exited with code: 141)
Press return to continue

which according to this question : [socket connection getting closed abruptly with code 141](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880606/socket-connection-getting-closed-abruptly-with-code-141) is a SIGPIPE signal.

Comment: It sounds like you might have a *crash*. Build a version of your program with debug information (add the `-g` flag) and then run in a debugger to see what it says.

Comment: With no code we cannot know the cause of the crash. Build a [mvce] and shows it here along with the error message. Currently your question is off topic because it lacks that code.

Comment: @SergeBallesta edited with a code sample

Comment: Probably unrelated, but you should do the `if (p == NULL)` check *before* you call `SSL_connect`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks, edited

Comment: It isn't valid to call `SSL_get_error()` *unless there was an error.*

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function and at least one `#include`. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem, then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Comment: @TobySpeight thanks for your input! The problem has been solved.

Comment: Re your edit, that is a brand new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unsure why it caused a crash, but `SSL_connect` is not the equivalent of `connect`: it  initiates the TLS/SSL handshake on an **already established** connection. As `sockfd` is not connected in your code, it fails and sets `connRet` to -1 causing an endless loop.

You should connect the socket immediately after its creation and before initiating a SSL handshake:

```
    if ((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype,
        p->ai_protocol)) == -1) 
    {
        perror("socket");
        continue;
    }
    /* connect at the TCP level */
    if (connect(sockfd, servinfo->ai_addr, servinfo->ai_addrlen)) {
        perror("connect");
        continue;
    }
    int fd = SSL_set_fd(connection, sockfd);
    ...
```

But anyway, you should control your program to remove possible endless loops, and be consistent in error messages: either use C++ stream `cout` or C FILE* `stderr`. And it would be better to properly close the socket if it could be opened.

Comment: You're a genious! Thank you so much!